# GsonBuilder setDateFormat for "2011-10-26T20:29:59-07:00"

Tags: java, date, gson

I'm getting a date/time in json as `2011-10-26T20:29:59-07:00`. What's the proper way to use `gsonBuilder.setDateFormat` to properly format this time?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The `-07:00` is the ISO 8601 time zone notation. This is not supported by `SimpleDateFormat` until [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). So, if you can [upgrade](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) to Java 7, then you can use the `X` to represent that time zone notation:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX").create();
```

On [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you would need to do some pattern matching and replacing on the JSON string first to replace the `-07:00` part by the RFC 822 notation `-0700` so that you can use `Z`:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();
```

or by the general time zone notation `GMT-07:00` so that you can use `z`:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz").create();
```

Comment: Helped me a lot thanks. Wish I have more than one upvotes. :)

Comment: you can see my answer below for a Java 6 solution with pattern matching.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I used `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX").create();` to get milliseconds also. 

I have not found a way (other than using a custom adaptor) to support both formats.

Comment: I'm using Java 8 (Android w/ Retrolambda), and I'm getting an error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'"

Comment: There is no Java 8 on Android - here you're stuck with something like JDK6.

Comment: On Java 6 it's possible to escape the Z character with single quote: `new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'").create()`. This way, no find and replace is needed

Answer (score 13):

For Java 8 (have not verified for Java 7), just use the pattern

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX
```

To get exactly the format of `2011-10-26T20:29:59-07:00`.

The time zone pattern is from [Java Date Time - Custom Date Format Patterns](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Date_Time/0150__Java_Custom_Date_Format_Patterns.htm)

- X

  > ```
  > Zone offset
  > Example:
  >     X       +09
  >     XX      +0930 
  >     XXX     +09:30
  >     XXX     -05:00
  >     XXXX    +093045
  >     XXXXX   +08:30:45
  > ```

Answer (score 8):

My api response date format is exactly same with yours, like this:

```
"weather": {
    "temperature": 31,
    "time": "2016-06-23T09:28:38+08:00"
}
```

in Android project, I use following code, both work for me.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
       .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
       .create();

// or, also work
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
       .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
       .create();
```

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"` doesn't work in Android, although I have configed use Java 8 in `build.gradle`.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

how do we know the date format we should set, in fact you can find the answer from the source code of `SimpleDateFormat.java`:

```
 * <p>Which produces this output when run in the America/Los_Angeles time zone:
 * <pre>
 *                     yyyy-MM-dd 1969-12-31
 *                     yyyy-MM-dd 1970-01-01
 *               yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1969-12-31 16:00
 *               yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1970-01-01 00:00
 *              yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1969-12-31 16:00-0800
 *              yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1970-01-01 00:00+0000
 *       yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31 16:00:00.000-0800
 *       yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000+0000
 *     yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31T16:00:00.000-0800
 *     yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000
 * </pre>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while since this was posted, but came accross it when trying to use GSON to parse an API response that had this date format. I figured I would share the 2 little functions I wrote using regex to find all the dates and change them to the format that GSON can then parse.

```
private static String cleanDateFormat(String json){ // takes in a string of JSON
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d[-\\+]\\d\\d:\\d\\d"); 
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(json);
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    while(regexMatcher.find()){
        regexMatcher.appendReplacement(buff, getSubOfMatch(regexMatcher));
    }
    regexMatcher.appendTail(buff);
    return buff.toString();
}
//then pull out the colon.
private static String getSubOfMatch(Matcher matcher){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(matcher.group(0));
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-3);
    return sb.toString();
}
```