# Parsing a JSON Response into a Java object

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am new to Android development. I have a node test server running that returns the following json post response

```
res.json({ userName: 'test@gmail.com', ratedOn: new Date(), rating: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) });
```

I am using gson to parse the response into an object
 Class Definition of the target class

```
public class RateWork {
    public int rating;
    public Date ratedOn;
    public String userName;

    public RateWork(int rating, Date ratedOn, String userName){
        this.rating = rating;
        this.ratedOn = ratedOn;
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

In the client(Android side) i am using volley to capture the response.

```
StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.API_POST_RATING,                                    

new Response.Listener<String>() {    
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d("TEST", response);
        RateWork rw = gson.fromJson(response, RateWork.class);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d("TEST", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Log of the response

D/TEST: {"userName":"test@gmail.com","ratedOn":"Sat Dec 09 14:10:49 GMT+05:30 2017","rating":3}

I get an exception at this line -> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException

```
RateWork rw = gson.fromJson(response, RateWork.class);
```

Please help fix the error.

Comment: Missing: 1. full exception description and trace. 2. The debug string value of 'response'

Comment: I have read all the answers. I couldnt find any that uses GSON.

Comment: If I had to guess, Gson doesn't know how to parse your Date  string into a Date object.

Comment: Anyways, one line of your exception doesn't tell us what the error is. Please edit your question to include the full stacktrace

Comment: removing the date property got the parsing to work. Let me figure out how to work out with the date. Thanks

Comment: Got it working by using -> gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create();

Answer (score 0):

Use this to create your Gson Object

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
   .setDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz").create();
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910734/gsonbuilder-setdateformat-for-2011-10-26t202959-0700) for more detail

Comment: At least use the correct format for the date in the question instead of copying a post

Comment: thanks for your help Gautam, i can take it forward with this using the required format.