# Correct Date format to use for GsonBuilder Date Format

Tags: java, date, gson, date-format, date-parsing

My client sends me a date in "2019-11-22T16:16:31.0065786+00:00" format. I am getting the following error:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
>   "2019-11-22T16:16:31.0065786+00:00"

The date format that I am using is:

```
new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ")
    .create();
```

Please let me know which format to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GsonBuilder setDateFormat for "2011-10-26T20:29:59-07:00"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910734/gsonbuilder-setdateformat-for-2011-10-26t202959-0700). See also: [Which Java Date format is this “YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00+00:00”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313005/which-java-date-format-is-this-yyyy-mm-dd-0000000000)

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for responding. I have 2 issues together here and your links provide solution to only one of them. The format I get is 7 digits of milli or nano seconds (0065786) followed by the time zone (+00:00). is there a date format to cover this format?. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This format can be handled by [DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223171/java-util-date-format-ssssss-if-not-microseconds-what-are-the-last-3-digits) instance of `DateTimeFormatter`. It is a part of `Java Time` package which was released together with `1.8` version. You should use `ZonedDateTime` to store values like this but we can convert it also to obsolete `Date` class.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Date;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateJsonDeserializer())
                .registerTypeAdapter(ZonedDateTime.class, new ZonedDateTimeJsonDeserializer())
                .create();

        System.out.println(gson.fromJson("{\"value\":\"2019-11-22T16:16:31.0065786+00:00\"}", DateValue.class));
    }
}

class DateJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(json.getAsString());

        return Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
    }
}

class ZonedDateTimeJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ZonedDateTime> {
    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(json.getAsString());
    }
}

class DateValue {
    private ZonedDateTime value;

    public ZonedDateTime getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(ZonedDateTime value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DateValue{" +
                "value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
DateValue{value=2019-11-22T16:16:31.006578600Z}
```

When you change `ZonedDateTime` to `Date` in `DateValue` class it will print this date with relation to your time zone.

See also:

- [java.util.Date format SSSSSS: if not microseconds what are the last 3 digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223171/java-util-date-format-ssssss-if-not-microseconds-what-are-the-last-3-digits)
- [Java Date toString contains a timezone… Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951765/java-date-tostring-contains-a-timezone-why)